# Moving data label in Google Charts (Bar) below the bars

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

There's an example of Google Charts with data label over the bars: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/googlecharts/googlecharts_bar_labels.htm

Is there any way to move the data labels below the bars (and color into black)? Like this:

[image]

Comment: there are no config options out of the box, but you can manually move the labels by changing the `'y'` attribute on the `<text>` elements when the chart's `'ready'` event fires...

Comment: @WhiteHat, thank you for giving this hint. The label data is quite deep in the DOM, but possible to manipulate. Don't know if it works fine on the 'ready' event, needs checking.

Comment: most likely you will need to use a `MutationObserver`, as the chart will move them back on interactivity, such as hover. I have some examples here, search google-visualization for "move annotations"...

Comment: @WhiteHat, thank you